# cannot create a function in ksh/bteq

Tags: ksh, teradata

I have this function that works for a co-worker, and I've seen where it works for others as well.  I have tried both << EOF, and <

I have added a simple use of the function as well for testing purposes.

```
 td_query() { bteq << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
 $(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
   DATABASE DBNAME;
   .set width 1000;
   .set titledashes off;
   $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}

td_query "select current_date;"
```

Unfortunately, when I save this and try to run the ksh file, I get the following error:

```
-ksh: .: syntax error: `<<' unmatched
```

Can anyone tell me what would cause this?

Comment: I have tried it both with and without the space.  I get the same result either way.

Comment: yes, you're right. I also tested with space after the EOF terminal, and didn't get `<< unmatched`. You've flagged your question w Teratada: Are you running on AIX? If so then you're most likely using an old ksh (but I don't think what your doing would be cause a problem there). As this works on someone else machine, you need to pare the problem down to a bare mininum test case where all .profile, etc files are the same. Its possible that something "above" this code is causing the trip-up. If I think of anything else I'll add it later. Good luck.

Comment: And of course the # 1 cause of mysterious problems is allowing your Unix code to be touched by a Windows machine (even just ftp). If that is a possibility, `dos2unix scriptName.sh` might help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid spaces both at `<<EOF` and the line starting with EOF.
And the line with EOF shouldn't have trailing spaces either.
First test with a simple script (no idents before EOF !).

```
td_query() {
   wc <<EOF
   $(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
   DATABASE DBNAME;
   .set width 1000;
   .set titledashes off;
   $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}

td_query "select current_date;"
```

And check the bteq program. Is het reading from stdin?
When I replace "wc" by "echo" in the script above, the script stops working!